# Using Proxy pattern to write a server a good idea?

Tags: java, design-patterns, proxy-classes

For a school project, I need to write a simple Server in Java that continuously listens on an incoming directory and moves files from this directory to some place else. The server needs to log info and error messages, so I thought I could use the Proxy pattern for this. Thus, I created the following ServerInterface:

```
public interface ServerInterface extends Runnable {

    public void initialize(String repPath, ExecutorInterface executor, File propertiesFile) throws ServerInitException;

    public void run();

    public void terminate();

    public void updateHTML();

    public File[] scanIncomingDir();

    public List<DatasetAttributes> moveIncomingFilesIfComplete(File[] incomingFiles);

}
```

Then I've created an implementation `Server` representing the real object and a class `ProxyServer` representing the proxy. The `Server` furthermore has a factory method that creates a `ProxyServer` object but returns it as a `ServerInterface`.

The `run`-method on the proxy-object looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void run(){

        log(LogLevels.INFO, "server is running ...");

        while( !stopped ){

            try {

                File[] incomingContent = scanIncomingDir();
                moveIncomingFilesIfComplete(incomingContent);
                updateHTML();
                pause();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.logException(e, new Timestamp(timestampProvider.getTimestamp()));
                pause();
            }

        }

        log(LogLevels.INFO, "server stopped");
    }
```

The functions that are called within the `try` statement simply log something and then propagate the call to the real object. So far, so good. But now that I've implemented the `run`-method this way in the proxy object, the `run`-method in the real object becomes obsolete and thus, is just empty (same goes for the `terminate`-method).

So I ask my-self: is that ok? Is that the way the proxy pattern should be implemented?

The way I see it, I'm mixing up "real" and "proxy"-behaviour ... Normally, the real-server should be "stuck" in the while-loop and not the proxy-server, right? I tried to avoid mixing this up, but neither approaches were satisfying:

- I could implement the `run`-method in the real object and then hand over the proxy object to the real object in order to still be able to log during the while-loop. But then the real object would do some logging, which is I tried to avoid by writing a proxy in the first place.
- I could say, only Proxy-Server is `Runnable`, thus deleting `run` and `terminate` from the Interface, but this would break up the Proxy pattern.

Should I may be use another design? Or I am seeing a problem where there is none?

Comment: Great question (Why the close vote?)

Comment: For a school assignment, I'd just log inline unless the point of the assignment is to apply patterns pervasively.

Comment: I'd 2nd @millimoose - keep it simple, although its great that you're thinking about these things.

Comment: @millimoose I agree that for a school assignment, I could easily find another solution. The reason I asked the question was also to better understand the way the proxy pattern is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely thinking in the right way. You've hit upon an interesting notion.

Features like *logging*, as you've described, are an example of what we call *cross-cutting concerns* in [Aspect Oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

- A cross-cutting concern is a requirement that will be used in many objects.

. . therefore, they have the tendency to ***break object oriented programming***. What does this mean?

- If you try to create a class that is all about moving files from place A to place B, and the implementation of a method to do that first talks about logging (and then transactions, and then security) then that isn't very OO is it? It breaks the single responsibility principle.

**Enter Aspect Oriented Programming**

This is the reason we have AOP - it exists to modularize and encapsulate these cross-cutting concerns. It works as follows:

- Define all the places where we want the cross-cutting feature to be applied.
- Use the intercept design pattern to "weave" in that feature.

**Ways we can "weave" in a requirement with AOP**

- One way is to use a Java DynamicProxy as you've described. This is the default in for example the Spring Framework. This only works for interfaces.
- Another way is to use a byte-code engineering library such as asm, cglib, Javassist - these intercept the classloader to provide a new sub-class at runtime.
- A 3rd way is to use compile-time weaving - to change the code (or byte-code) at compile-time.
- One more way is to use a java agent (an argument to the JVM).

The latter two options are supported in AspectJ.

**In Conclusion:**

It sounds as though you're moving towards Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP), so please check this out. Note also that the [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) has a lot of features to simplify the application of AOP, though in your case, given this is a school assignment, its probably better to delve into the core concepts behind AOP itself.

***NB: If you're building a production-grade server, logging may be a full-blown feature, and thus worth using AOP. . in other cases its probably simple enough to just in-line.***

Comment: Point to note: what the OP is trying to do cannot be accomplished with run-time weaving. (Because proxies can't intercept calls to `this`, which the OP already found out, and is the same with Spring AOP interceptors.) It'd require load-time weaving or compile-time weaving, both of which are a setup hassle. I'm not sure what you meant by your bytecode engineering suggestion - how do they intercept the classloader when you're not using a JVM agent?

Comment: I'm not sure of all the nitty-gritty details, but the key point is they *don't* require a Java agent. My understanding is at the point that a class is loaded, they will return a new instrumented sub-class. . asm and cglib work at the byte-code level, while Javassit is very interesting it that it uses a decompiler! This makes it easy to use, although also very slow. . . Spring's transaction management of concrete classes uses (or used to) use cglib. . (Although these days you can now also use AspectJ).

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! I'll check out some of that concepts you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in this case:

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
> called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
> observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
> usually by calling one of their methods.

Your `Observable` will observe changes in directory, by time pooling, or as already was suggested here, with `WatchService`. Changes of directory will notify **Observer** which will take action of moving files. Both **Observable** and **Observer** should log their actions.

You shold also know that Observer pattern became a part of Java JDK by implementing  `java.util.Observable` and `java.util.Observer`.

Comment: The question is asking how to extract the logging **out of** whatever will implement moving files. In your scenario, the `Server` would be the class that implements `Observer`, and thus have to "log its actions", which the OP is trying to get out of the `Server`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your proxy aware of the real object. Basically your proxy will delegate the call to run method to the real implementation.

Before the delegation, the proxy first logs the startup. After delegation, the proxy logs the "shutdown":

```
// Snapshot from what should look like the run method implementation
// in your proxy.

public ServerInterfaceProxy(ServerInterface target){
    this.proxiedTarget = target;
}

public void run(){
    log(LogLevels.INFO, "server is running ...");
    this.proxiedTarget.run();
    log(LogLevels.INFO, "server is running ...");
}
```

This implementation can also be perceived as a Decorator pattern implementation. IMHO, I believe that to some extent (when it comes to implementation) Proxy and Decorator are equivalent : Both intercept/capture behavior of a target.

Comment: And how would you log something when the server is running in your implementation?

Comment: Well, your server services can be also wrapped by logging decorators. Now, this can become cumbersome depending on the scale of your project. Under a complex server assumption I agree that a declarative solution is more appropriate. So to summarize, All depends on the scale of your project (which is basically simple according to your question)!

Answer (score -1):

Look at Java 7's WatchService class.

Using Proxy behaviour for this is almost certainly overkill.

Comment: -1: Completely missing the point of the question. The proxy is used to handle logging, what the server actually does and how it accomplishes this is ancillary.

Comment: From someone whose comment was "log inline", this is hypocritical to say the least.

Comment: I know "log inline" was a workaround or tangential suggestion. That's the **reason** I posted it as a comment, and not an answer. Besides, it's not the only issue with yours. (Like the fact you didn't bother producing as much as a link to the javadocs, much less actually demonstrate how using `WatchService` would obviate the need for a logging interceptor.)